# How to force launch images instead of launch screen on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, xcode6

How do I disable launch screen for my app for iOS 8?

I want to have old-fashioned images for that.

If that is not possible, how do I setup my LaunchScreen.xib to show correct image based on device?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just delete LaunchScreen.xib if you want to use images.  Under `Images.xcassets`, you will be able to assign your static images when you create `LaunchImage` just like how it used to be.

And yes, delete the value in `Launch Screen File` selector in your target's settings.

Comment: If you are not using the XIB or storyboard approach your app will not show up as "optimized for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+".  

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Comment: @Petter - what do you mean by storyboard approach? Launch Images on storyboard? Is there any tutorial/documentation about that?

Comment: @SpaceDog - I have only used this with a xib file. Apple refers to "a XIB or storyboard file" in the iOS Human Interface Guidelines that I linked to. Hence, I assume you can use either a xib file or a storyboard file.

Comment: @Calvin Cheng Where can I found that Launch Screen File? Which file

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers also make sure you **deleted the app** from simulator/device after the changes you've made.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way. Delete the LaunchScreen.xib. Then go to General tab in your target and delete the line in Launch Screen File selector.

It does not let you confirm empty screen, but you can overcome this by selecting any source file in Project navigator after you emptied the line.

Answer (score 1):

Also fill the "Asset Catalog Launch Image Set Name" in your target's Settings with the name of the LaunchImage you created in your Image Assets. The field is blank when the project is created with a default LauchScreen.